# How to permanently remove/drop stored procedure from a SQL Server database. But the procedure definition exists after dropping

Tags: sql-server

I have dropped a stored procedure from a SQL Server database and I could not find the stored procedure under "Programmability /stored procedures" folder in SQL Server Management Studio.

But If I search the deleted stored procedure name in `.MDF` and `.LDF` (open in Notepad as text and search for the deleted procedure), then I could find the full stored procedure. How to completely remove the stored procedure?

I have used `Drop Procedure [dbo].[sp_Test]`

And there is no error. But I should not see the deleted procedure and if it is opened in notepad or any text editor.

Comment: Just curious why you care to go looking for it with such intensity? `But I should not see the deleted procedure` - who says? What official resource claims the procedure fragments are immediately removed from the MDF? It would make changing code very expensive operation if you rebuild your entire db file every time. If you're concerned about security you should perhaps look to other weak areas first such as who has file based access to the MDF, the server etc

Comment: Databases do not "wipe" areas that have been deleted or dropped. You need to force the cleanup. There are various ways to do this. I don't know if `sp_clean_db_free_space` works or if you will need to rebuild the database with a backup.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Every time do not want to recreate the database but still would like to know how to cleanup dropped sored procedure shown in text editor.

Comment: But **why** do you want to remove the stored procedure text from the MDF? Who is looking at it and why is that a problem? Why is it so sensitive? This is a very unusual requirement.

Answer (score 4):

There is no guaranteed, supported method to erase data from a inside a SQL Server database.  Creating and loading tables, rebuilding indexes, creating and dropping procedures, etc will *probably* end up overriding the data.  But it's not guaranteed.

If you need this, copy everything you want to retain into a new database.

Comment: Just curious: Does turning on/off TDE change something?

Comment: Turning on TDE will guarantee that the data (deleted or otherwise) cannot be read directly from the database files without the encryption key.  But it's not documented that the TDE encryption scan will clean up data in unallocated extents, or on unused parts of a page.